# Implement COM interface registered in system

Tags: c++, com, atl

How can i implement and extend COM interface registered in system. Let's asume it is delivered with some software, not part of OS.
Should i write IDL first ?
I know Microsoft's ATL samples, but none of them shows what i'm looking for.

For example here is idl for Foxit Reader Control, generated with OleView

```
   [odl,
uuid(62F8A765-322B-41E3-B767-2D057829D66D),
  helpstring("IFoxitCtl Interface"),
  dual,
  oleautomation
]
interface IFoxitCtl : IDispatch {
    [id(0x00000001), propget, helpstring("property src")]
    HRESULT src([out, retval] BSTR* pVal);
    [id(0x00000001), propput, helpstring("property src")]
    HRESULT src([in] BSTR pVal);
    [id(0x00000002), helpstring("method OpenFile")]
    HRESULT OpenFile(BSTR strFilePath);
    [id(0x00000003), helpstring("method PrintFile")]
    HRESULT PrintFile();
    [id(0x00000004), helpstring("method SetProgress")]
    HRESULT SetProgress(
                    int nOffset, 
                    int nSum);
    [id(0x00000005), helpstring("method postMesage")]
    HRESULT postMessage([in] VARIANT strArray);
    [id(0x00000006), propget, helpstring("property messageHandler")]
    HRESULT messageHandler([out, retval] VARIANT* pVal);
    [id(0x00000006), propput, helpstring("property messageHandler")]
    HRESULT messageHandler([in] VARIANT pVal);
};
```

What should i do to implement this interface?
Notice: i took random interface from registered in OS, if you have working example with any other COM interface please share it

I've tried to use "Implement Interface" feature in visual studio but many interfaces are not available there

Comment: Depends on your tooling. What you *will* need is interface definition, in some form or another; preferably IDL as it can be transpiled into C, C++ or whatever language you use. If you write the definition yourself, make sure it matches the original definition. Also note that IDispatch is special.

Comment: COM can't be taught in a SO answer. You should use ATL tutorials (if you choose ATL). For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/active-template-library-atl-tutorial or https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38254/Writing-Simple-COM-ATL-DLL-Using-it-with-dotnet or a book like "Beginning Atl Com Programming" or "Developer’s Workshop to COM and ATL 3.0" and then you can come back with a more precise question

Comment: @numzero I've got IDL of interface i want to use (generated with oleview). So i should attach i to project , right?  Why "Implement interface" shows subset of registered interfaces? OleView "see" them all.

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks. These resources focus on writing own classes and interfaces. What i'm looking for is implementing interfaces registered in system.

Comment: Implementing an interface is exactly what these resource focus on. To make it short, you can't reimplement or "extend" something that's already provided.

Comment: @SimonMourier Looking at CodeProject example you've shared. Let's say i want to implement ISimpleCom. As it is not part of my solution, but interface found in registry, what should i do next? Use OleView to generate IDL, put it in solution and select it in "Add connection point" wizard?

Comment: An interface provided by the system should be documented, ex: IMoniker: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-imoniker in this case it's documented, there's a .h (sometimes an .idl), the system provides some implementation (CreateFileMoniker, CreatePointerMoniker, etc.), but you can reimplement it if you want. If it's not documented (not sure exactly what you mean by "found in the registry"), there's not much you can do (or start using a disassembler and dig). Devils hide in details, your question is not focused enough.

Comment: @SimonMourier Is it possible to implement interface used in question "IFoxitCtl Interface"?  In this example, IDL is all i need or not? I do not have header files etc. That is what this question is about :) I understand that if one of parameters is pointer, without any documentation we do not know what can be passed to function and something can go wrong.